# CountVectorizer not able to handle input text

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pos-tagger, countvectorizer

I have a train set of data illustrated below. The elements are part of speech tags.

```
[('NNS', 'MD', 'VB', 'DT', 'NNS', 'IN', 'JJ', 'NN', ',', 'VBG', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'JJ', 'IN', '.'), ('NNS', 'CC', 'NN', ',', 'RB', 'RB', 'IN', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'IN', 'WDT', 'PRP', 'VBZ', 'NN'), ('PRP', 'MD', 'VB', 'PRP', 'RB', 'IN', 'DT', 'NNS', 'VBG', 'DT', 'NNS', 'IN', 'PRP$', 'NN', '.'), ('NNS', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'TO', 'VB', 'NN', 'NNS', 'CC', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN', 'IN', 'NN', 'CC', 'NN', '.'), ('JJ', 'NNS', 'MD', 'VB', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'NN', 'IN', 'NNS', '.'), ('DT', 'NNS', 'MD', 'VB', 'NN', 'CC', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN'), ('DT', 'NNS', 'MD', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NN', 'CC', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NNS', '.'), ('RB', 'VB', 'VBN', 'IN', 'NN', 'CC', 'MD', 'VB', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', '.'), ('PRP', 'VBP', 'NNS', 'IN', 'VBG', 'NNS', 'IN', 'NNS', 'CC', 'NNS', '.'), ('DT', 'NNS', 'MD', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NNS', 'IN', 'NN', 'CC', 'NN', 'IN', 'DT', 'NNS', ',', '.'), ('PRP', 'TO', 'VB', 'NNS', 'TO', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NNS', 'VBG', 'IN', 'PDT', 'PRP$', 'NNS', 'CC', '.'), ('NNS', 'NNS', 'CC', 'VB', 'DT', 'IN', 'PRP$', 'NNS', 'IN', 'NN', 'CC', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN', '.'), ('NNS', 'TO', 'VB', 'JJ', 'WRB', 'VBG', 'IN', 'CC', 'IN', '.'), ('PRP', 'VBP', 'NNS', 'TO', 'VB', 'DT', 'JJ', ',', 'JJ', 'CC', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'WDT', 'MD', 'VB', 'PRP$', '.'), ('NN', 'CC', 'NN', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NNS', '.'), ('PRP', 'MD', 'VB', 'RB', 'TO', 'VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'CC', '.'), ('JJ', 'NNS', 'TO', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'PRP$', 'NNS', '.')]
```

now when I do:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',ngram_range=(2,4))
vectorizer.fit(train_set)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I don't see my train set any tuples.As far as I know it is a list of list,no?

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Well the `vectorizer` wants the `train_set` to be a **list of strings**, and you give them **a list of tuples of strings**. So obviously it is not working.

Comment: what is a tuple?and how I can change the input so it works?

Comment: A tuple is something that looks like `(element,element,element)`...

Comment: When you use `()` round braces, it is meant for a tuple. Change them to square braces `[]` and then try.

Comment: Actually, whats your use case. Describe more